# Where can I find good AREL documentation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, documentation, arel

I'm trying to learn as much as I can about AREL. But I'm not sure what to look at.

I found some [documentation on rubydoc](http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/master/frames), but it doesn't seem very good in terms of showing what are the "public API"/accessible things I can do. For example, I could not find any information on the "includes" method.

So, how exactly to learn most of what AREL has to offer? (i.e. without delving into the source code)

Comment: maybe consider choosing the most up voted answer? :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this will be useful :

https://github.com/brynary/arel

And an interesting asciicast :

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3

Comment: Unfortunately, that's hardly any documentation. I can't even find the word "includes" on that page. I was looking for something more thorough..

Comment: includes is an active record method, so it won't probably be there, or just may be as an example.

Comment: There is an asciicast that also has some nice info, i'm adding it to the post.

Comment: Other than those resources, i don't think there is something more detailed to tell you the truth.

Answer (score 18):

I got tired of reading tests and code, in the arel tree, so I put some [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/flah00/activerecord-arel) together. They cover v2.x, I haven't even looked at v3 yet.

Comment: That's an excellent set of slides, thanks for putting them together!

Comment: i'm glad someone found them useful

Comment: @PhilipC as I go through your slides, I get redirected to Facebook. Bizarre.

Comment: @DavidJames, can you be more specific? I just clicked through and wasn't redirected

Comment: @PhilipC The problem was temporary -- probably on my end.

Comment: The post is asking for a password.

Comment: mmm, someone defaced the blog ... when we migrated it, we apparently didn't deign to bring our content with us... sigh :/

Answer (score 8):

I wrote an article about Arel a few weeks ago ([The definitive guide to Arel, the SQL manager for Ruby](http://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html)). It walks through the whole library and explains how things work internally and how you can use it from your own application.

Comment: This was really helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, I'm having a real hard time finding doc too.  The Arel test suite might be of some use:

https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/test/test_select_manager.rb

Answer (score 2):

Complete documentation is here: http://rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/master/Arel  Look in the modules for specific methods.