# Convert query from SQL to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How I can get the same result using ActiveRecord?

```
SELECT categories.* FROM categories
INNER JOIN levels ON levels.id = categories.level_id where levels.description <= "Medium"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be precise without more details, but it should be something like that:

```
Category.joins(:level).where('levels.description <= "Medium"')
```

I think this should also do the trick:

```
Category.joins(:level).where(Level.arel_table[:description].lteq('Medium'))
```

Comment: I am getting this error ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'levels' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?. Level has_many category and category belongs_to Level

Comment: What is this arel_table and lteq in here? is the any documentation for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688386/where-can-i-find-good-arel-documentation